# C# multiple conditions with if and els if

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am currently taking a course in c#. One of the exercises is the following.

Ask the user to enter the ring colors of the first 3 rings as text (e.g. green). Then show the value of this resistor. So if the user enters in sequence: red - purple - red

Then the program will show:

This resistor has value of 2700 Ohms

I want to solve this with “if and els is”. I already have the following code but I am stuck on one part.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the first ring color");
string firstRingColor = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Enter the second ring color");
string secondRingColor = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Enter the third ring color");
string thirdRingColor = Console.ReadLine();

if (firstRingColor =="black" || secondRingColor =="black" || thirdRingColor == "black")
{
    Console.WriteLine("0");
}
else if (firstRingColor == "brown" || secondRingColor == "brown" || thirdRingColor == "brown")
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
}
```

with the execution of this program it only executes the last part. Is there a way to save the result and display it afterwards

Comment: It is not clear what the issue is, based on your question alone.
The value of your code is also questionable - if you have to type the whole color name for every ring, you might as well print a cheat sheet and look at it every time.

Comment: ... that aside, the values you have to determine are per ring, not if any ring has that color - resistors come in a variety of values for resistivity.  This means you will need a function that takes color and returns value, and call that function several times, depending on the rings' count, then do some math with those values

Comment: First of all, thank you for your quick answers.  The value of the colors are  " https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/res_2.html".   I am fairly new to programming. I also realize that my code so far is not fantastic. I've also thought about using a const int red = 2; But each color has a value and I have to enter three colors then my program has to display the full value. But I can only display 1 value for now. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: @code you wouldn't be able to use `int red = 2` (and maybe `nameof(red)==consoleInput`...), because also `int red=100`, when it comes from the multiplier ring;   See my answer, check it as an answer if it works for you

Comment: The answers provided are well intended and will help do what you need, but, may be over-your-head of understanding at this time.  Have you learned about: Arrays, Lists, Dictionaries, Loops?  The reason it only processed ONE is because the if/ELSE.  It will only test for the first one that qualifies, not each individually as you need.  As a beginner learning, edit your post and provide more details of SOME of the other you ARE familiar with so an answer can be provided within your current scope of knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your homework code

NOTE that this code is for 5- and 6-band resistors and your sample of `red-purple-red` calculates to 2700ohm for 4-band resistors, so you need to enter 'red-purple-black-red' to convert it to 5- and 6-band format... or you can remove reading `r3`

```
// entry point
void Main()
{
    // define the values associated with colors for resistivity
    var rColorValues = new Dictionary<string, float> {
        {"black",0},
        {"brown",1},
        {"red", 2},
        {"gold",3},
        {"yellow",4},
        {"green",5},
        {"blue",6},
        {"purple",7},
        {"silver",8},
        {"white",9},
    };

    // colors associated with the multiplier ring
    // similar strategy can be used for tolerance and temperature coefficient rings, not shown here
    var multColorValues = new Dictionary<string, float>{
        {"black", 1},
        {"brown", 10},
        {"red",   100},
        {"gold",  1000},
        {"yellow",10000},
        {"green", 100000},
        {"blue",  1000000},
        {"purple",10000000},
        {"silver",0.01f},
    };
    
    // read the colors for 3 rings.This works for 5 and 6-band resistors
    // for 4-band resistor the third ring has to be 'black'
    float r1 = ReadColorValue("First ring:", rColorValues);
    float r2 = ReadColorValue("Second ring:", rColorValues);
    float r3 = ReadColorValue("Third ring:", rColorValues);
    
    // get the color for the multiplier ring
    float mult = ReadColorValue("Multiplier ring:", multColorValues);
    
    // calculate the ohms
    int ohms = (int)((r1*100+r2*10+r3)*mult);

    Console.WriteLine($"{ohms} Ohm resistor");
}

// this method writes the prompt, reads a line and returns the value from the dictionary, if one matches
float ReadColorValue(string prompt, Dictionary<string, float> colorToValueMap)
{
    while (true) // keep asking for input until a valid one is received
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
        var consoleInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        if (colorToValueMap.ContainsKey(consoleInput)){
            // if the color name is found - return the value associated with it
            return colorToValueMap[consoleInput];
        }
        // ... otherwise - help the user
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Unknown value. Enter one of: "+string.Join(", ",colorToValueMap.Keys));
    }   
}
```

Comment: A+ - I hope @OP will give you a mention when this is submitted

Comment: Although very good example, but I bet in no way NEAR the level of their coding in class / learning has extended them :)

Comment: @DRapp you're right, given the sample code in the question. I wrote such an answer (research on the subject matter, code I would actually use etc), so the OP has a *reason* to look up what a `Dictionary` is or what `string.join` does. It's also the reason for the comments to be more detailed than I would normally consider. I hope @code is encouraged by receiving useful answers and coding looks less scary to them

Comment: I agree with you and normally DO very heavy commenting in my code.  Your code is clean, but MAY be over their head (at this time), but if homework would be beyond their scope of class which is all I was trying to shoot for.  I do like your answer though.

Comment: Indeed I have not really seen much yet,We have only just started. arrays, case's I have yet to see so I have only seen if and else if.and | , & . To use in my if and else if